# Using HTMLAgility pack to extract value from a Xpath using c# console app

Tags: c#, xpath, google-chrome-devtools, html-agility-pack

I have the following line of HTML code and I used google chrome for xpath.

```
<DIV id=TasheelPaymentCtrl1_dvPayment>
<TABLE border=1 cellSpacing=0 borderColor=black cellPadding=7 width=625 align=center>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD class=ReceiptHeadArbCenterHead1 width=320>المسمى </TD>
<TD class=ReceiptHeadArbCenterHead1 width=75>دفع إلى</TD>
<TD class=ReceiptHeadArbCenterHead1 width=75>القيمة</TD>
<TD class=ReceiptHeadArbCenterHead1 width=75>الكمية</TD>
<TD class=ReceiptHeadArbCenterHead1 width=75>المجموع</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD class=ReceiptHeadArbCenterHead>رسوم وزارة العمل</TD>
<TD class=ReceiptValueArbCenter>MOFI</TD>
<TD class=ReceiptValueArbCenter>3</TD>
<TD class=ReceiptValueArbCenter>1</TD>
<TD class=ReceiptValueArbCenter>3</TD>
<TR>
<TD class=ReceiptHeadArbCenterHead>رسوم الدرهم الإلكتروني</TD>
<TD class=ReceiptValueArbCenter>MOFI</TD>
<TD class=ReceiptValueArbCenter>3</TD>
<TD class=ReceiptValueArbCenter>1</TD>
<TD class=ReceiptValueArbCenter>3</TD>
<TR>
<TD class=ReceiptHeadArbCenterHead>رسوم مراكز الخدمة </TD>
<TD class=ReceiptValueArbCenter>MOFI</TD>
<TD class=ReceiptValueArbCenter>47</TD>
<TD class=ReceiptValueArbCenter>1</TD>
<TD class=ReceiptValueArbCenter>47</TD>
<TR>
<TD class=ReceiptHeadArbCenterHead1 colSpan=4>المجموع</TD>
<TD class=ReceiptValueArbCenter>53</TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></DIV>
```

I want to extract values 3, 3, 47 and 53

I tried using this xpath

```
 var gf = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='TasheelPaymentCtrl1_dvPayment']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[5]");

                foreach (var node in gf)
                {


                    Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText); //output: "3"
                }

                var sf = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='TasheelPaymentCtrl1_dvPayment']/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[5]");

                foreach (var node in sf)
                {


                    Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText); //output: "3"
                }
                var tf = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='TasheelPaymentCtrl1_dvPayment']/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[5]");

                foreach (var node in tf)
                {


                    Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText); //output: "47"
                }
var Allf = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='TasheelPaymentCtrl1_dvPayment']/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]");

                foreach (var node in Allf )
                {


                    Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText); //output: "53"
                }
```

but i am getting null object exception..
I used Google chrome developer tools to copy the xpath. I am getting null point exception . How can extract value ..
My question is why I am getting null point reference exception, is there any mistake in xpath value?
Please help me.

Comment: *Where* are you getting the NullReferenceException?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @DanielHilgarth , I am getting null point reference exception in for each loop   "gf"

Comment: So, it looks like the XPath is not working. Are you sure that the indexes are one-based? I would think that this XPath looks more correct with zero based indexes: `//div[@id='TasheelPaymentCtrl1_dvPayment']/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]`

Comment: @DanielHilgarth please explain what is one-based and zero-based. i am not sure about that

Comment: Just try the new XPath. *zero based* means that the first item in an array has the index 0. *one based* means that the first item in an array has the index 1.

Comment: I found the solution. <tr> is not properly closed. is there anyway solve to overcome without closing <tr>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have discovered, some of your XPath expressions don't work because the `<tr>` tags are not all closed.

Therefore, you will need to cater for this in your XPath expressions:

- `//div[@id='TasheelPaymentCtrl1_dvPayment']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[5]` - no change
- `//div[@id='TasheelPaymentCtrl1_dvPayment']/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[5]` - should be `//div[@id='TasheelPaymentCtrl1_dvPayment']/table/tbody/tr[2]/tr/td[5]`
- `//div[@id='TasheelPaymentCtrl1_dvPayment']/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[5]` - should be `//div[@id='TasheelPaymentCtrl1_dvPayment']/table/tbody/tr[2]/tr/tr/td[5]`
- `//div[@id='TasheelPaymentCtrl1_dvPayment']/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]` - should be `//div[@id='TasheelPaymentCtrl1_dvPayment']/table/tbody/tr[2]/tr/tr/tr/td[2]`

Comment: Good, but i came up with this option. clearing html documents.  HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                    
                    text = Regex.Replace(text, "<tr[^>]*>(?:(?!</?tr>|</tbody>|</table>).)*?(?=<tr[^>]*>|</tbody>|</table>)", "$&</tr>", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    doc.LoadHtml(text);
                    doc.OptionAutoCloseOnEnd = true;